# Error SQL0204 - Not found HTTPCLOB in SYSTOOOLS type *N

Tags: sql, rpgle, websphere

I am trying to use HTTPCLOB function to issue a POST request to a web service, but when I run the program I get the error as in the title, no matter my efforts to match the fields' type of my SQL statement to those of the function.
Here D-specifications:

```
D url             s           1024a   varying             
D httpHeader      s           1024a   varying inz         
D requestMsg      s          32000a   varying inz         
D resHttpHeader   s          32000a   varying inz         
D resMsg          s          32000a   varying inz
```

This is the SQL statement:

```
url = 'https://labelservice.gls-italy.com/AddParcel';          
requestMsg = 'XMLInfoParcel: ' + xmlData;                      
httpHeader = 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;'
           + ' Content-Length: ' + %char(%len(requestMsg))     
           ;                                                   
exec sql                                         
  select cast(responseMsg as clob(2G))           
  //   , cast(responseHttpHeader as varchar(512))
  into :resMsg                                   
  // , :resHttpHeader                            
  from table(systoools.HTTPCLOB(                 
          URL => cast(:url                       
                 as varchar(2048)),              
          HTTPMETHOD => 'POST',                  
          HTTPHEADER => cast(:httpHeader         
                 as clob(10K)),                  
          REQUESTMSG => cast(:requestMsg         
                 as clob(2G))                    
             )                                   
       ) as httpRequest                          
;
```

where xmlData is an xml-variabile with some content in it.
I assume there might be other errors because this is my first try using this function.
Anyway, as for the IBM documentation here 
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_73/rzajq/rzajqudfhttpclob.htm
variables' types match.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the first error was a typo, then when the function is used as a table in the from clause the verbose version should be used instead.

Answer (score 1):

SYSTOOLS has two 'O's, not three.

IE: SYSTOOLS vs SYSTOOOLS

Comment: I can't believed it! I didn't see it at all. So, now the program doesn't even compile with error "SQL0390: the use of HTTPCLOB function in SYSTOOLS is not valid". Also, the product option is correctly installed and working, as command CHKPRDOPT PRDID(5770SS1) OPTION(33) doesn't show any error.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the spelling error noted in the other answer...

The SYSTOOLS functions for rest calls were made available in v7.1 as part of level 23(?) of the Database group PTF...

You linked to the v7.3 documentation, are you actually on v7.3?

Comment: No, the system is running V7R2, but I didn't find the corresponding documentation for it.